# PyInstaller cftime module not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-venv, netcdf4

I am beginning to work with PyInstaller to create exe file from my Python scripts, but i have problem with netCDF4 module. I am working on windows 7.
The code is really simple:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
out = Dataset("file.nc", "w")
out.GA = "ok"
out.close()
print("ok")
```

I started creating a virtual environment using

```
python -m venv v_env_x1
```

and activate it with

```
Scripts\Activate
```

then I install on v_env directory the netCDF4 and PyInstaller modules

```
pip install netCDF4
pip install PyInstaller
```

finally I created the exe file with

```
PyInstaller script.py --onefile
```

The command generates the exe file, but when I try to run it this error appears:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cftime'**

If I use `pip list` command however the cftime module is present in the virtual environment!
Moreover if I use the command

```
python script.py
```

the code runs normally.
Someone can help me? Below there is the result of `pip list` command

```
Package                   Version
------------------------- ---------
altgraph                  0.17
cftime                    1.2.1
future                    0.18.2
netCDF4                   1.5.4
numpy                     1.19.1
pefile                    2019.4.18
pip                       20.2.2
pyinstaller               4.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2020.7
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0
setuptools                39.0.1
```

Thank you

Comment: add the flag --hidden-imports cftime to your command. Because you don't import the module directly, pyinstaller may not realize that it's a needed dependency.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!